# CodeIgniter not getting routes to work

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm totally new to PHP frameworks, so appologies for opening a very basic question.

I've been battling and reading away but can't get my static page displayed.

**Controller Pages()**

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {
    public function index($page = 'index'){
        if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
            echo 'error';
            show_404();
        }
        $data['title'] = $page;
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

**Config**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mysite'; //wamp local server
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**Routes**

```
$route['pages'] ='pages/index'; //my route

$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

According to my understanding the routing system works as follow

`$route = class_name/method`

In my views folder I have the folllowing which should be called in the controller and mapped in the routing system, yet I get a 404. Note that CodeIgniter is correctly installed since I get the welcome page.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: and how u r accessing the url for not found page

Comment: @pradeep `http://mysite/pages/index` which matches the `$route` right? Please confirm if im accessing correctly

Comment: is http://mysite/pages gives u error

Comment: @pradeep nope it doesnt that actually displayed the index page. So what did I do wrong in my route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will work for you :

change your route.php like this :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/index';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/index/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Pradeep thank you and yes that works but would the `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/index/$1';` (:any) route not lead to problems? 

Say Ive got a new controller `users()` would that not redirect to `pages` since the `(:any)` wildcard is used?

Comment: it is when you have single controller, if u have multiple controller you have to write new definition for them

Comment: see this  : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html#static-pages